# Flutter adding SingleChildScrollView or ListView to part of widgets in screen

Tags: flutter

I try to add simple scroll view widgets such as `SingleChildScrollView`,`ListView` for par of my widget in this below implemented code,Although hours i tired to add this widgets for parent of `Column` widget i get error and i can't do that,

i'm wondering why this implementation should be get our time to adding simple scroll view

```
class FragmentNewTicket extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FragmentNewTicketState createState() => FragmentNewTicketState();
}

class FragmentNewTicketState extends State<FragmentNewTicket> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                child: Card(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
                            child: Text(
                              '111111111',
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'ShabnamLight', fontSize: 12.0),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                )),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
                            child: Text(
                              '1111111',
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                            validator: (value) {
                              int len = value.length;
                              if (len == 0) {
                                return Strings.fieldIsEmpty;
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            },
                            maxLines: 6,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'ShabnamLight', fontSize: 12.0),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                )),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          Center(
                            child: RaisedButton(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Text(
                                  '11111',
                                ),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0))),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the code, it looks fine to me. Can you post full code that has error?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad no problem. you can only copy `Scaffold` parent widget on your sample code

Comment: I ran your code, but it worked fine after including both `ListView` and `SingleChildScrollView` as parent of `Column` separately, can you edit the post with code that runs in error?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad error:  `Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: Is above code giving you that error? It's working fine in my emulator.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad my post updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Spacer` widget from your code because the parent of `Column` is `SingleChildScrollView`.

You can't combine these two widgets, because `SingleChildScrollView` doesn't have fix bound, and `Spacer` wants to take up the remaining space left, so they contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

It works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iUkl.png)

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            child: Card(
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                            child: Text('asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda asfdasasda asjdalksjda '))
                      ]))),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```